# What do these 2 Ghidra warnings mean?

Tags: ida, disassembly, arm, ghidra, exploit

When disassembling ARM binaries in Ghidra, I often see these warnings:

```
                /* WARNING: Could not recover jumptable at 0x0747c198. Too many branches */
                /* WARNING: Treating indirect jump as call */
```

What do they mean? What's the underlying architectural concept I should learn about to understand the cause of these issues?

Here's an example from a real program, seen in Ghidra's disassembly:

```
    if (param_2 == 0x78) {
                /* WARNING: Could not recover jumptable at 0x0747c198. Too many branches */
                /* WARNING: Treating indirect jump as call */
      uVar3 = (*DAT_0747c19c)();
      return uVar3;
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

From [Ghidra.re](https://ghidra.re/courses/GhidraClass/Advanced/improvingDisassemblyAndDecompilation.pdf):

> Sometimes you will see warnings in the decompiler view stating that there are too many branches to recover a jumptable.
> One reason for this is that there actually is a jump table, but the decompiler can’t determine bounds on the switch variable

For your example, this is saying there may a jump table (which is really just an array of pointers), but the decompiler can't figure out what the different possibilities for `param2` are.

Ghidra recommends:

> In such cases, you can add the jump targets manually and then run the script SwitchOverride.java.
> Note: To ﬁnd such locations in a program, run the script FindUnrecoveredSwitchesScript.java.

Comment: I tried that but makes no difference. In my case, the template for at least some switches is (segmented Intel code): switch_table: array of (16b value, 16b code offset) switch_code: MOV SI,(#cases-1)*4 next_case: CMP AX, word ptr CS:[SI+switch_table] JNZ no_match JMP word ptr CS:[SI+switch_table+2] no_match: SUB SI,4 JNS next_case I selected the JMP instruction in disassembler, added the switch addresses manually with RE, ran the SwitchOverride.java code, recompiled the function. No difference. Well one difference, I do see the switch addresses in the function graph, so it does seem to have pi